# Angular - Conditional validator is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I have an Angular form where the following validation should happen:

1. checkbox === ticked then validate the input else no validation
2. checkbox === unticked then no validation but rechecking should enable the validation

I am having issues when on the page load the checkbox is unticked and the input box does not have any value the validation doesn't trigger which is expected. However, the input box validation doesn't trigger immediately after clicking the checkbox when the input is empty.

Here is the code:

```
private myFormValidator(predicate: Function, validator: ValidatorFn): ValidatorFn {
        return ((formControl: FormControl) => {
            if (!formControl.parent) {
                return null;
            }
            let error = null;
            if (predicate()) {
                console.log('predicate()');
                return validator(formControl);
            }
            return null;

        });
    }


 this.partnerInvoiceDetailsForm = this.fb.group(
            {

                rebates: new FormGroup({
                    territories: new FormGroup({
                        rebateTier: new FormControl(null, [
                            this.myFormValidator(() => this.rebateActive(this.rebateIdMap[1]).value, Validators.required)]),
                        rebateValue: new FormControl(null),
                        rebateActive: new FormControl(null)
                    })
                   }
        );

        // console.log(this.partnerInvoiceDetailsForm.get('rebates.territories.rebateTier'));
        this.partnerInvoiceDetailsForm.get('rebates.territories.rebateActive')
            .valueChanges
            .subscribe(value => {
                console.log(value)
                this.partnerInvoiceDetailsForm.get('rebates.territories.rebateTier').updateValueAndValidity();
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1: With `valueChanges` observable**

During the "rebates.territories.rebateActive" value change event, you can add the validator programmatically via [`addValidators`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#addvalidators) and [`removeValidators`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#removevalidators) methods. Note that you have to pass the same reference for the validator function added into validators in order to remove it correctly.

```
const myFormValidator = this.myFormValidator(
  () => this.rebateActive(this.rebateIdMap[1]).value,
  Validators.required
);

this.partnerInvoiceDetailsForm
  .get('rebates.territories.rebateActive')
  .valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
    console.log(value);

    if (value)
      this.partnerInvoiceDetailsForm
        .get('rebates.territories.rebateTier')
        .addValidators(myFormValidator);
    else
      this.partnerInvoiceDetailsForm
        .get('rebates.territories.rebateTier')
        .removeValidators(myFormValidator);

    this.partnerInvoiceDetailsForm
      .get('rebates.territories.rebateTier')
      .updateValueAndValidity();
  });
```

[Demo Approach 1 @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z9dwj7?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

---

**Approach 2: Modify `myFormValidator` ValidatorFn by adding `dependency` parameter.**

If you allow to modify the `myFormValidator`, you can add `dependency` parameter and implement the logic to check the value of `dependency` to proceed/exit the logic.

```
private myFormValidator(
  predicate: Function,
  dependency: string,
  validator: ValidatorFn
): ValidatorFn {
  return (formControl: FormControl) => {
    if (!formControl.parent) {
      return null;
    }

    if (!formControl.parent.get(dependency)?.value) return null;

    let error = null;
    if (predicate()) {
      console.log('predicate()');
      return validator(formControl);
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

The key point of implementing this approach is you have to trigger `this.partnerInvoiceDetailsForm.get('rebates.territories.rebateTier').updateValueAndValidity()` when the `rebates.territories.rebateActive`'s value is changed.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.partnerInvoiceDetailsForm = this.fb.group({
    rebates: new FormGroup({
      territories: new FormGroup({
        rebateTier: new FormControl(null, [
          this.myFormValidator(
            () => this.rebateActive(this.rebateIdMap[1]).value,
            'rebateActive',
            Validators.required
          ),
        ]),
        rebateValue: new FormControl(null),
        rebateActive: new FormControl(null),
      }),
    }),
  });

  this.partnerInvoiceDetailsForm
    .get('rebates.territories.rebateActive')
    .valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log(value);

      this.partnerInvoiceDetailsForm
        .get('rebates.territories.rebateTier')
        .updateValueAndValidity();
    });
}
```

[Demo Approach 2 @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xqtod5?file=src/app/app.component.ts)